# How do i get the value of a certain child node in spinner when i select value from previous spinner?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the value of the course section into my spinner when I select the course name from my previous spinner. But it is not finding the key and its value but it is there. I don't know where I am doing wrong.

This is my firebase database structre:

```
"Courses Details" : {
    "Bs-BBA" : {
      "-MVuhKkfxjHkZmTfsITM" : {
        "Economics" : {
          "courseName" : "Economics",
          "courseSection" : "A",    // These are the values that i am tryng my spinner to get populated with
          "dayOfCourse" : "Tuesday",
          "endingTime" : "1:30Pm",
          "programName" : "Bs-BBA",
          "startingTime" : "12:00Pm"
        }
      }
    },
    "Bscs" : {
      "-MVWl1uq9fA4AlYRfMIv" : {
        "Data structure" : {
          "courseName" : "Data structure",
          "courseSection" : "A",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Monday",
          "endingTime" : "9:30AM",
          "programName" : "Bscs",
          "startingTime" : "8:00AM"
        }
      },
      "-MVY9hGxrp8Lz4JTOefy" : {
        "OOP" : {
          "courseName" : "OOP",
          "courseSection" : "A",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Thursday",
          "endingTime" : "9:00AM",
          "programName" : "Bscs",
          "startingTime" : "8:00AM"
        }
      },
      "-MVYHM0c7cMLersoUl2i" : {
        "Marketing Fundamental" : {
          "courseName" : "Marketing Fundamental",
          "courseSection" : "A",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Thursday",
          "endingTime" : "9:00AM",
          "programName" : "Bscs",
          "startingTime" : "8:00AM"
        }
      }
    },
    "Bsse" : {
      "-MVYHB3X_d4UozbBUDa3" : {
        "Marketing Fundamental" : {
          "courseName" : "Marketing Fundamental",
          "courseSection" : "A",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Thursday",
          "endingTime" : "9:00AM",
          "programName" : "Bsse",
          "startingTime" : "8:00AM"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

For example, if I select the course name from program Bs-BBA or from any of the courses it should populate the course section spinner on the basis of my selection from the course name spinner.

Below is the java code for this that I have implemented so far:

```
 spinnerForCourseSection = findViewById(R.id.course_sec) ;

        spinnerForCourseSecArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        spinnerForCourseSecArrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(AssignCoursesToFaculty.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerForCourseSecArrayList);
        spinnerForCourseSection.setAdapter(spinnerForCourseSecArrayAdapter);

        spinnerForCourseName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {

                // if ( parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals(spinnerForProgramNameArrayList) )
                //{ }

                String selectedValueFromSpinnerProgramName = spinnerForProgramName.getSelectedItem().toString() ;

                String selectedValueFromSpinnerCourseName = spinnerForCourseName.getSelectedItem().toString() ;

                ValueEventListener listener;

                final DatabaseReference rootRef;
                rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Courses Details");

                listener = rootRef.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
                    {

                        //if( snapshot.child(selectedValueFromSpinnerCourseName).exists() )
                        //{

                        spinnerForCourseSecArrayList.clear();


                        for( DataSnapshot programNameKey: snapshot.getChildren() )
                        {

                            for (DataSnapshot courseNameKey : programNameKey.getChildren())
                            {

                                for (DataSnapshot courseNameDetails : courseNameKey.child(selectedValueFromSpinnerCourseName).getChildren())
                                {

                                    if (courseNameDetails.child("courseSection").exists())
                                    {

                                        spinnerForCourseSecArrayList.add(courseNameDetails.child("courseSection").getValue().toString());

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }

                        spinnerForCourseSecArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        //}

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }

        });
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: 1) Did you already step through the code in a debugger? If you set a breakpoint on the first line inside `onDataChange`, you see if it trigger and then step through it line by line to see where it goes wrong. 2) Please *never* leave `onCancelled` empty, as you're ignoring possible programming error. At its least it should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: I did put breakpoints and check the values but it is not reading the courseSection Variable from database

Comment: Please be more explicit, as there is no `courseSection` variable in the code you shared. When you step through the code, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do? And what happens on the latest line before that, that *does* still do what you expect it to do?

Comment: courseSection variable is in the database not in code. In code, I want to fetch its value and it is not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution for the above question is below:

```
spinnerForCourseSection = findViewById(R.id.course_sec) ;

        spinnerForCourseSecArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        spinnerForCourseSecArrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(AssignCoursesToFaculty.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerForCourseSecArrayList);
        spinnerForCourseSection.setAdapter(spinnerForCourseSecArrayAdapter);

        spinnerForCourseName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {


                String selectedValueFromSpinnerProgramName = spinnerForProgramName.getSelectedItem().toString() ;

                String selectedValueFromSpinnerCourseName = spinnerForCourseName.getSelectedItem().toString() ;

                ValueEventListener listener;

                final DatabaseReference rootRef;
                rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Courses Details");

                listener = rootRef.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
                    {


                        spinnerForCourseSecArrayList.clear();


                        for( DataSnapshot programNameKey: snapshot.getChildren() )
                        {

                            for (DataSnapshot randomIdKey : programNameKey.getChildren())
                            {

                                for (DataSnapshot courseNameKey : randomIdKey.child(selectedValueFromSpinnerCourseName).getChildren())
                                {

                                    String courseNameDetail = courseNameKey.getKey();

                                    if( courseNameKey.child(courseNameDetail).getKey().equals("courseSection") )
                                    {

                                        spinnerForCourseSecArrayList.add(courseNameKey.getValue().toString());

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }

                        spinnerForCourseSecArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error)
                    {

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }

        });
```